# How to handle "create database permission denied in database master" in windows Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I opened "ASP.NET SQL Server Setup Wizard" using the command apsnet_regsql from visual studio 10 command propmpt(Run as Administrator).

In that wizard I selected Windows Authentication instead of Sql Authentication. When I tries to connect to Master Database I am getting the following exception

An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallCommon.sql'. The SQL error number is 262 and the SqlException message is: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. Creating the TestDB database

and the SqlException is:

create database permission denied in database 'master' in windows authenticAtion.

By the exception I understand that I don't have permission to create database. But how and where can I get permission to do that.

i have SQL Server 2008 in my system which comes as default with Visual Studio 2008 only.

So please help me and give a solution for my problem.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the reason why this is happening is because the user does not have the permission in sql sever to do any modification one of the ways to solve it would be to go to security  folder chose user select properties might be permissions and make this user a dbadministrator or other advanced role than login with this user and try to create the database

here are couple of articles

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd568727.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178630(v=sql.90).aspx

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLChangeOwner.aspx

Comment: i don't have SQL Management Studio installed in my system to change the user propoerties. i have SQL Server 2008 in my system which comes as default with Visual Studio 2010 only.

Comment: well you still need to use some sort of console to even execute queries

Comment: can you please guide me how to do that or post a link for reference?

Comment: not that. how to execute queries using console to add login user as dbadmin

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/using-sqlcmd-to-execute-sql-scripts/422